# My question has been flagged as a possible duplicate of a question that doesn't solve my problem

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions

My question [here (Q2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328106/how-do-i-retrieve-an-icon-of-a-particular-size-from-a-resource-file)  has been tagged as a possible duplicate of [this question (Q1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025401/selecting-the-size-of-a-system-drawing-icon).

I can't get the answer in Q1 to solve my problem. I wonder if it is a bug?  When I put a trace on the variable rname I see it never contains ".ICO"

Should I be commenting on Q1 - asking if there is a bug (when it has 8 votes), or have I done the right thing asking the question in my own words?

Comment: If you edit and improve the question with the newly collected information based on the duplicate question, then we may cast reopen votes for you.

Comment: I have edited it.  Is there a way to ask people to vote it back?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much what you just did.

Comment: As you got it solved and posted your solution in the other question, there's really no point to reopen your question now. You did the right thing, just a side note: pay more attention to your formatting when posting code blocks.

Comment: oops - cut and paste not necessarily good enough